# What does @$(shell ...) mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile

I've met this code in makefile:

```
push: build
    @$(shell aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
    docker tag $(CONTAINER) $(DOCKER_REPO):latest
    docker push $(DOCKER_REPO):latest
```

Can you explain what does '@' do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` at the beginning of a recipe line in a Makefile causes `make` to execute this line silently.

`$(shell)` is a Make function to run a shell command, and insert its output as text (somewhat similarly to a command substitution in the shell itself).

In some more detail, the output from `aws ecr get-login` is a `docker login` command which should be evaluated by the shell in which you want to log in to AWS.

So after the `$(shell)` is evaluated, your recipe becomes something like

```
push: build
    @docker login -u secrets -p moresecrets https://still-more-long-messy-secret-or-at-the-very-least-vaguely-sensitive-stuff.amazonaws.com
    docker tag $(CONTAINER) $(DOCKER_REPO):latest
    docker push $(DOCKER_REPO):latest
```